# playing flash movies in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, prototype, lightbox

I'm using JQuery and Prototype in this web application that I'm developing.  I'm looking for a way to use Lightbox v2.04 by Lokesh Dhakar to play flash movies.  If its not possible using the Lightbox v2.04 then what other ways can I accomplish the shadowing overlayed flash video pop-up with jquery and/or Prototype?  The reason I'm set on v2.04 is because I'm using it already as an image gallery.  I'm using flv type flash files if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [LightWindow](http://www.stickmanlabs.com/lightwindow/) to display arbitrary HTML before, but my experience shows flash and LightWindow don't mix that well.

We had a FLV player in the background (not in the LightWindow), and LightWindow caused flicker in some browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is using JQuery's [Thickbox plugin](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/).

Comment: I've used this before with very favorable results.

Answer (score 1):

Three commercially free lightbox methods that will support swf and flv formats are [PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/), TopUp, and Bumpbox.  [Here](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/) is a list of other options.  Sorry, I can only give two hyperlinks as a new user.

Answer (score 1):

[Highslide](http://www.highslide.com), [Prettyphoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone) and multibox are best for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Lightbox Gone Wild](http://particletree.com/features/lightbox-gone-wild/)

Answer (score 0):

I've used lightwindow 2.0 to display flash movies with success for the portfolio section at www.brainclippings.com.

b

Answer (score 0):

FlashInLightbox for displaying flash inside Lightbox
http://code.google.com/p/flashinlightbox/

Answer (score 0):

[PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyPhoto/) is a great jQuery plug-in that supports flash and image galleries both. Note that at the time I wrote this, version 2.2.5 does not support flash, but a download for vesion 2.2.2 is still available, which does support flash.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and went for [multibox](http://phatfusion.net/multibox/).

As well as images and flvs, it works with wmvs, quicktime, realmedia and mp3.

Documentation is sparse, but good enough for you to be able to integrate is quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to throw in my vote for [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/). I've used it for numerous projects, and it kicks some serious a$$.